# Questions about shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, g++, shared-ptr, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've written the exercise12.28 in C++ Primer, but I got stuck in shared_ptr. The code can be compiled, but it will crash when it executes. I've thought that I misused the shared_ptr. Please help me to check the following code:

```
map<string, shared_ptr<set<size_t>>> word_line;
//some performances to deal with word_line, everything goes normally
string word;
cin >> word;
map<string, shared_ptr<set<size_t>>>::iterator find_word = word_line.find(word);
//the programm crashes when the following codes execute
int line_size = (*(find_word->second)).size();
```

Comment: You use `world_line` without initialized it. Like raw pointer, if you don't allocate memory, you get undefined behavior. Take a look at `std::make_shared`

Comment: I initialized `word_line` in the omitted code and runs well. The error just happens around `find_word` and `line_size`.

Comment: You have to compare `find_word` to `word_line.end()` to be sure you have found something. (if `find_word` is equal to `word_line.end()` you don't have found anything)

Comment: @Vogel_guo don't omit relevant code. Create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to check whether the word exists in the map. If the key doesn't exist, then `find` returns `word_line.end()` in which case `find_word->second` has undefined behaviour.

Even if the word was found, you forgot to check whether the shared pointer points to null or not. If it does point to null, then `*(find_word->second)` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: thank you for your reminding in comment area, I've checked my code literally and indeed found a logic mistake in my omitted code which hasn't been posted in the question. Originally I've thought something went wrong with the usage of shared_ptr.